# Read file with NodeJS returns `ENOENT no such file or directory`

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a file, but I always got the error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open \'SB01028A.RET\'`. The file name is correct, and exists because I put the file in my Home/sentbox directory.

What I did wrong here ?

**Code:**

```
function downloadFile () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const testFolder = `${require('os').homedir()}/sentbox`

      fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err)
        }
        files.forEach(fileRetorno => {
          const retorno = fs.readFileSync(fileRetorno, 'UTF8')
          return resolve(retorno)
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: does `file` have a meaning? btw you can only resolve once from a promise. so using it in a loop will only resolve the first value.

Comment: @RolandStarke I know, but for this little example is not a problem right now. I just need to read 1 file for this moment.

Comment: `fileRetorno` is only the file name. not the complete path.

Comment: @RolandStarke Very good. I need put the `${testFolder}/${fileRetorno}` on `readFileSync` method

Comment: Perform a dynamic `require` is bad practice. Use `import` instead or `require` at the top of the file.

Comment: Why bother to use of promise if you end up using `readFileSync` ?

Comment: Why do you have a call to `resolve()` inside of a `.forEach()` loop?   Only the first call to `resolve()` will do anything.  All the others will be ignored.  Are you trying to just read one file?  Or is the intent of your code to read all the files in that directory?  Please edit your question to describe the desired function of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of things wrong in your code like

- Using synchronous file reading within a promise when you could be making your file reading asynchronous
- Using `try/catch` in an asynchronous context without wrapping that in a  `async/await` function
- You're not using the results of `fs.readdir()` correctly.
- Attemping to resolve/reject a promise that could have already been resolved or rejected
- Using `require()` in a loop, and in an asynchronous context

`fs.readdir()` is going to return all the entry names within that directory, both files and directories, as an array. Before you can call `fs.readFile()` you'll need to check if the entry is a file or directory and you'll need to `join()` the path to the directory read with `readdir()` in this case, `testFolder`, with the entry name.

When returning using Promises (`async/await` wraps promises but still uses them), you only can resolve each promise once. So resolving the same promise multiple times to return different values doesn't work, the same is true for rejecting multiple times. Instead, you'll need to return your values in an Array or an Object. For the scenario in the above code, using an Object would be more ideal since you can associate the file contents to a key for reference and better access later on.

I've used `async/await` to clean up this code, this will give you the synchronously development approach while getting the functionality of promises. You can read more about `async/await` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). I've also promisified all of the asynchronous version of the needed `fs` functions using [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

The code below will

1. Read all of the entries in `testFolder`
2. Filter the entries array to only include files by calling `stat()` for each entry and checking if it is a file.

   - `stat()` will return a `fs.Stat` object that can tell us if the entry is a file via `stat.isFile()`. Since `Array#filter()` is only expecting a boolean result for each entry interated over, the result of `stat.isFile()` can be returned directly
3. Iterate over the `files` array with `Array#reduce()` and call `readFile()` for each file, returning the contents on an object with each file name as a key to the contents

---

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {promisify} = require('util')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir)
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)
const stat = promisify(fs.stat)

const downloadFile = async () => {
  const testFolder = `${os.homedir()}/sentbox`
  // Get all the entries in the directory async
  const entries = await readdir(testFile)

  // We only want the file entries returned
  const files = entries.filter(async entry => {
    let stat = await stat(path.join(testFolder, entry))
    return stat.isFile()
  })

  return Promise.all(files.reduce(async (filesContents, file) => {
    let filepath = path.join(testFolder, file)
    fileContents[file] = await readFile(filepath, 'utf8')
    return fileContents
  }, {}))
}
```